# Slicer changes other filters in the pivot table

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, slice

I am having difficulties setting slicer in excel.

I have multiple pivot tables (PT) in one workbook, which are connected to one slicer. Some PT have 2 and some 3 filters set. When I add a new connection to the slicer or, e.g. change the name of the slicer, some filters reset in all pivot tables. Since I have to reset them every time that happens, it totally misses the purpose of the slicer.

Here are some print screens to explain it better.

The slicer sets the number of months ("O"). In the working PT you can see filter set for field "MD", "O" (which is in the slicer) and "Row Labels". When I change something in the Slicer the PT changes the filter for "Row Labels", and it doesn't work. As you can see on the 2nd PT print screen, the PT doesn't show any values, however other filters are fine. I always have to clear the filter for "Row Labels" and then choose needed values again. Is there any way to solve this problem and use slicer for this purpose?

[image: Slicer]

[image: Working Pivot Table]

[image: Pivot Table after the change in slicer]

I will be very grateful for help, since I can't find a solution to this problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of what you are asking, but do you really need to both have a slicer and a filter?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Yes I do. I have multiple pivot tables (PT), which are updated monthly, and the slicer helps me to change the month in all PTs. I save time by this, but since after the change in the slicer part of the PTs collapse, It does not do it's job. I found out that the only PTs that stop working after the slicer change are the ones where I have a filter set as "between", where I have values from 3400 to 3799. It's really weird, I just have to rewrite the 3400 value and it works again... Maybe the problem is with the zeros?